# jquery ui datepicker changing date based on time of day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a store for a friend. They very specific shipping standards that I need the datepicker to follow. The only deliver on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. Also, at 12pm on each of these days the picker needs to change the next available date to the following Mon. Wed,. or Fri. Example: If it is 12pm on Wednesday the soonest someone could select as a date is the following Monday. 12pm would need to become unavailable for that Friday.

I have found pieces of code that should add this functionality, but do not know how to add them to the code that I currently use to make the change effective.

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#date").datepicker( { 
beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: +2,
    maxDate: '+6M',
    firstDay: 1

});

function nonWorkingDates(date){
    var day = date.getDay(), Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3, Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;
    var closedDates = [[7, 29, 2009], [8, 25, 2010]];
  var closedDays = [[Tuesday], [Thursday], [Saturday], [Sunday]];
    for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
        if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
            return [false];
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 &&
        date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] &&
        date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
            return [false];
        }
    }

    return [true];
}




]);
```

Please explain as specifically as possible. I am a code noob. Something that I can copy and paste into a specific place would be ideal.

Comment: "at 12pm on each of these days the picker needs to change the next available date to the following Mon. Wed,. or Fri." I'm not sure I understand.  If it's 12:01 PM on Wednesday, why can't I pick Friday for delivery?

Comment: You can, you just mistakenly interpreted "the following Mon., Wed., or Fri." as a group of days instead of individual days.  Certainly could've been worded a bit better...

Comment: After working on this a bit and re-reading your post several times, I see why Marc was confuse.  It might help if you can be more specific.  I think what you are wanting is: 1) today's date is always disabled, 2) if it is before noon, the user can pick the next deliver date, 3) if it is after noon, the user cannot pick the next delivery date.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just need to determine if the date passed in is the next delivery day.  If it is, and it's past noon, then disable that date.  I'm sure someone with more experience could do it more elegantly, but what I came up works at least for today (it's Wednesday, and past noon, and it blacked out Friday).

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#date").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: nonWorkingDates,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: +2,
        maxDate: '+6M',
        firstDay: 1
    });

    function nonWorkingDates(date) {

        var day = date.getDay(),
            Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3,
            Thursday = 4, Friday = 5, Saturday = 6;

        var closedDates = [ [7, 29, 2009], [8, 25, 2010] ];

        var closedDays = [
            [Tuesday], [Thursday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < closedDays.length; i++) {
            if (day == closedDays[i][0]) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < closedDates.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == closedDates[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == closedDates[i][1] && date.getFullYear() == closedDates[i][2]) {
                return [false];
            }
        }

        var currentDay = new Date();

        //if it's not past noon, we don't need to do the next check
        //so return true
        var currentHour = currentDay.getHours();
        if (currentHour < 12) {
            return [true];
        }

        //determine if the date passed in is the next delivery day
        var nextDeliveryDay = 0

        switch (date.getDay()) {
            case 1:
                nextDeliveryDay = 3;
                break;

            case 3:
            case 5:
                nextDeliveryDay = 2;
                break;
        }

        //if date minus the number of days to the next delivery date
        //equals today's date, then return false
        var testDate = new Date(date);
        testDate.setDate(testDate.getDate() - nextDeliveryDay);

        //normalize the time of day for comparison
        currentDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (testDate.getTime() == currentDay.getTime()) {
            return[false];
        }

       return [true];
    }
});
```

Comment: This is based on my understanding that if it's past noon on a Monday, Wednesday, or Friday, that the next delivery day is to be unavailable.  I.e., past noon on Monday = Wednesday unavailable, past noon on Wednesday = Friday unavailable, and past noon on Friday = Monday unavailable.  It is not clear to me what was intended by "12pm would need to become unavailable for that Friday."